# Will grouping be applied to computed metrics in GA?

Tags: google-analytics, metrics, dimensions

Will grouping be applied to computed metrics in GA?

Let me show you an example of what I am asking here.
I have a computed metric. It has the following formula `{{metric1}}/{{metric2}}` and it is called `metric`.

Now I want to create a report. Will dimension be taken into consideration when computing the computed metric value?

For instance, total aggregated `metric1` value is 10, and total aggregated value for `metric2` is 2. Now, out of those 10 in `metric1` 5 have dimension called `dimension` being equal to `dimension1`, 2 have the dimension being equal `dimension2` and 3 `dimension3`.

If I create a report with two columns `dimension` and `metric`, will I get the following three lines:

`dimension1` 2.5 (which is 5/2)

`dimension2` 1 (which is 2/2)

`dimension3` 1.5 (which is 3/2)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, that's exactly how calculated metric supposed to work. you can easily cross check this by creating a custom report with `dimension` and `metric`, `metric1` and `metric2`